# Button's 'Press' and 'Release' events

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF, C#,
I have a custom button based on button base class.
And I need to process button's events such as 'Press' and 'Release'.
The WPF doesn't allow to create two events handlers for a single button.
So I'm looking for a solution.

**A logic exampl**e:

- button_1 pressed --> event handler --> do something;
- button_1 released --> event handler --> do something;

Could anyone share a working example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "*WPF doesn't allow to create two events handlers for a single button*" is totally wrong. Just attach handlers for MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp or the respective Preview events.

Answer (score 1):

As @Clemens alluded in his comment above the events you want are `PreviewLeftMouseButtonDown` for pressed and `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` for released (or `PreviewMouseDown` and `PreviewMouseUp` if you would like to respond to any mouse button when processing the events).

**WPF**

```
<Button Content="Click me!"
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" />
```

**C#**

```cs
private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    /* Respond to the event */
}

private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    /* Respond to the event */
}
```

---

**EDIT**

After posting I realized what you meant by this statement:

> The WPF doesn't allow to create two events handlers for a single button. So I'm looking for a solution.

When adding event handlers in XAML only a single event handler can be wired up (just like in my example).  If you needed to wire up more than one handler to a single event you would need to do that using the `+=` operator in the C# code behind file.

However, that doesn't apply to what the intent of what you were trying to accomplish since the *pressed* and *released* events are 2 separate events anyway.